# why can't download my email into local disk to parse it?

Tags: python, email

I have login my gmail account and download the second email  from inbox mailbox into `/home/mymail`.

```
import imaplib
import email
user="yyyy"
password="xxxx"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
con.select("INBOX")[1][0]  
result,data=con.fetch(b'2', '(RFC822)')
with open("/home/mymail","w") as f:
    f.write(data[0][1])
```

Now i want to parse it from local file.

```
import email
s=email.message_from_file("/home/mymail")
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'.

But `email.message_from_string(data[0][1])["Subject"]` works fine,it can't be parsed when downloaded into a file in the local disk.

Comment: Have you tried making a file handle as `open("/home/mymail")`?

Comment: think tobias_k  `email.message_from_file(open("/home/mymail"))["Subject"]`  works fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function expects a `file` object, not a `str` with just the filename.

> ```
> message_from_file(fp, *args, **kws)
>     Read a file and parse its contents into a Message object model.
> ```

Try making a file handle, like you did for writing to the file, then it should work.

```
import email
with open("/home/mymail", "r") as f:
    s = email.message_from_file(f)
```